# Codeigniter/PHP: Should i create an image loader or access images directly?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I'm working on a project where i get images through an API from another site, and save the images locally on my server. I've been thinking, and i can't decide if i should create a loader that displays the image, or just access the specific images directly? Is there any security concerns if i access them directly? Before i save the images on the server, i validate the content and check if it is a valid image, so i will always have valid images to display.

The image loader would work sort of like this. I create a controller (call it "load" for example). Then i could just call load with the image as a param, sort of like this:

```
http://example.com/load/file_name.jpg
```

And then i get the image through the load controller and display it. Is there any advantage to doing so or is it okay to access the image directly?

Comment: You web server can serve files faster than PHP, however it can't read your database to check permissions.

Comment: The files will be available for everyone, no limits. I don't see a specific reason as to why i would need it, but i often see other people use it, so i was wondering if there is any reason for me to use it? You bring up a good point that it's faster to serve the image without PHP, but if there is some advantage to display it with PHP it might be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a use case of why someone (in this case, me) would serve images via PHP:

On one of my applications, users can upload avatar images. These images are processed on upload, names changed into hashes, and stored in the filesystem. The hashed name is stored in the database in a table that associates the photo's hash, the user id, and indicates whether or not this is their chosen profile photo.

If I was only using a single image size on the website, I would have just stored the image path and whether it was their profile image and have been done with it. However, the site has multiple locations in which the image can be displayed and they are varying sizes. Depending on the size of the image that is requested, I check to see if a size close to it has been generated. If it has, then I send a jpeg header, use `readfile` on the image location and serve the image. If it hasn't, then I take the originally uploaded image, resize it to the size I need, store it in the filesystem, and serve it.

This way, I am not creating 5+ images every time someone uploads an image. The images are generated on-demand, both distributing cpu time and reducing filesystem usage because some image sizes may never be requested.

So, essentially, if these apply to you, you do not need to serve via PHP/CI:

- not restricting access
- don't need dynamic resizing
- not storing images outside of the webroot

If you're curious, a request to one of my images looks like this:

`http://domain.com/photos/view/3d643a9cecaf8ae849be7ab094579698/s-128/photo.jpg`

Broken down:

`http://domain.com/[controller/view]/[image hash]/[square, rectangular, or original]-[size in px]/photo.jpg`

This serves an image with the following path:

`http://domain.com/images/uploads/3d/64/3a9cecaf8ae849be7ab094579698/3d643a9cecaf8ae849be7ab094579698_s_128.jpg`

I store the images in sub directories so that there *are* collisions and therefore avoid filesystem limits due to max files per directory and so on. I could also move the images outside of the webroot so that they are physically inaccessible to the web. Serving via PHP also has the added benefit of not exposing your upload directory's location.

I know the answer was long-winded, but I hope it helps you come to a decision.

Comment: Precisely the answer i needed. The second point can actually save me a lot of time and resource, i'm definitely gonna take that in mind. I also didn't know there was a limit as to how many files there can be in a folder. Yes, i'm gonna need a loader, and i'm also going to have to restructure my image folders. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to help! It's definitely not going to be trivial to implement, so good luck!

Answer (score 1):

An image loader as described has the obvious disadvantage that for each image that is displayed the framework has to be instantiated.
A better alternative would be an image helper which could be used to perfom any required modifications (watermarking, resizing, caching) on the images and output the image url so that the image can be delivered by the webserver without additional calls to the framework.

Comment: An image loader doing watermark and resizing should never be called dynamically, because this essentially is a waste of CPU if you do not store the result as well for every other user. As there is an import step mentioned, any image work could be done in this step before images are made available.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make your images better if they are sent out via PHP. The data is the same, and if there is no requirement of limiting access to a specified user group (aka public access), then I'd opt for the direct access.

Comment: Oh i know the image output will be exactly the same. I was just wondering if there is some advantage to displaying it with PHP. I mean, i guess i could store statistics about the images if i wanted to, but that's pretty much the only advantage i can think of. And i don't need any stats about when images are loaded etc, so that would be useless. Also, it's faster to load it directly from the server. Thanks for the input!